Definition of molecular vibrational coordinates
The wavefunction of a molecule is a function $f(x_1,\ldots,x_N)$ taking the coordinates of the $N$ atoms in the molecules (we ignore the electronic motion) and returning a complex number.
Conventionally the problem is attacked by "separating" the translational, rotational, and vibrational motion.
In the absence of external fields the momentum of the center-of-mass is conserved and so the translational motion rigorously separates out.
So from the original $3N$ coordinates we can eliminate the 3 center-of-mass coordinates $X = \frac{\sum_{n=1}^N m_n x_n}{\sum_{n'=1}^N m_{n'}}$.
The $3N - 3$ coordinates remaining should describe the rotational and vibrational motion of the molecule.
The vibrational coordinates are conventionally defined as the subspace of distortions of the equilibrium geometry $x^o_n$ which do not generate neither center-of-mass momentum nor angular momentum, i.e. the $3N-6$ (or $3N-5$ for a linear molecule) "modes" $e_{in}$ where
$$
\sum_{n=1}^N m_n e_{in} = 0
$$
and
$$
\sum_{n=1}^N m_n \left( x^o_n \times e_{in} \right) = 0
$$
where $\times$ indicates the normal cross product.
This definition, which is certainly reasonable, seems to imply that, given an arbitrary nuclear configuration $x_1,\ldots,x_N$, there is a unique "decomposition" $X \in \mathbb{R}^3$, $O \in SO(3)$, and $\Delta x_i \in \mathbb{R}$, $i=1,\ldots,3N-6$ such that:
$$
x_n = X + O \left( x^o_n + \sum_{j=1}^{3N-6} \Delta x_j e_{jn} \right)
$$
the rotational coordinates then being taken to be the 3 euler angles characterizing the rotation $O$.
Is it straightforward to prove that this decomposition exists? That it is unique?
